# Python adding boolean and integers abstraction

Tags: python, int, boolean

Basically, I'm unsure why:

```
red, green = 44, 43
purple = red + green
print(red + green != purple + purple / purple - red % green)
// Returns False
// Essentially => red + green != purple + 0.0

print(red + True + 0.0) // Returns 45.0
```

I'm unsure of what is causing the difference? As green != purple gives a result of True also, so why does the abstraction cause a difference in value?

Comment: Have you considered evaluating the expression based on operator precedence? Also, what outputs are you expecting in both the cases?

Comment: Actually I initially expected a syntax error, but I'm wrong. However this situation puzzles me even greater

Comment: trying to save a couple of parentheses is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) rules wrong. Essentially, the expression gets evaluated as follows:

```
red + green != purple + purple / purple - red % green
 = 44 + 43 != 87 + 87 / 87 - 44 % 43   # substitution
 = 87 != 87 + 1 - 1                    # perform / and % first
 = 87 != 87                            # sum
 = False                               # not equal
```

As for the second one, `red + True + 0.0`, `True` gets promoted to `1`, and the sum returns `45`, then adding `0.0` promotes the int to a float.

Comment: ah I see, I was thinking it would be more of 44 + True + 1 - 1 actually thats why

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to work as intended,
the first print is false since the left expression (red + green) matches the right expression (purple[red + green] + 0).

Since you checked whether they are different (by using != between the two expressions), you got False.

I think you confused the way python checks conditions.
When you use a comparison operand, python will first evaluate both sides of the operand, then compare both of the sides.

You wrote "As green != purple gives a result of True also", but the actual comparison is "(red + green) != purple".